# Development of Browser ToolBar

Tags: c#

I want to make a browser toolbar for Windows that should work for existing browsers like Firefox (2.x, 3.x) and Chrome as well in c#.net. I have read some articles on accomplishing this task and found some good stuff.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [besttoolbars.net](http://www.besttoolbars.net/products/toolbar/toolbar_business/)?